# How do I make 3 divs, have a total height of 100%, when their size is variable?

Tags: html, css

So I have one div which is the full browser height (100%), lets call it 'x'. I then have 3 divs which are contained inside it, they can be called 'a', 'b', 'c'. The height of div 'a' is the height of one paragraph. The height of div 'b' changes completely depending on the browser. The height of div 'c' should fill the remaining browser height so c=100-a-b. If any of this is unclear, feel free to ask a question. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you search before you asked?

Comment: Can you clarify your question , i do not think you talk about colums

Comment: @GCyrillus Cleverly confused question... LoL.

Comment: search for css flex.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use-case for flex boxes. You need to define a container with height of `100%`, you can position it absolute. And give a `flex` container layout for the container. Hard to explain but your solution is:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.flex-container {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; border: 1px solid #999; min-height: 250px;}
.flex-item {border: 1px solid #99f; margin: 5px; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works except for one small problem. If I have too much content in one of the flex items, the content causes the flex item to overflow out of the container, how can I fix the problem so that the flex item div becomes scrollable instead?

Comment: Don't set the height on the parent. I gave a `min-height` just for the fiddle. @AlexWetton Give `overflow: auto` for the parent.

Comment: So the sum of the content for container 1,2 and 3 will always bee to great for it to display simply at 100%. I want container 1 and 3 to be able to display all of their content with no overflow, but container 2 to scroll vertically when there is overflow. When I set no height to the flex container, the second box does not have overflow, it just causes the container to go beyond 100% height. Does this make sense? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did it work for you or not buddy?

Comment: Keep parent height 100%, and just give `nth-child(2)` as `overflow: auto` will work for you.